# Query to return all records (including all associated data) where at least one associated data matches requirements

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tables:

```
Users
Roles
RolesUsers
```

Associations:

```
User hasMany Role through RolesUsers
Role hasMany User through RolesUsers
```

What I want is to get all **users** along with their all **roles** that (user) contain **at least one role** that matches given requirements.

I use this query to get all users that are associated to `Role.name = 'admin' or 'member'`.
It works but along with each `User` it returns only `Roles` that match `name` from the query. And if user is associated with role with name `author` it wont be returned - how I can include ALL associated roles?

```
SELECT 
    "Users".*, 
    "Roles"."name" AS "Roles.name", 
    "Roles"."id" AS "Roles.id", 
    "Roles.RolesUser"."createdAt" AS "Roles.RolesUser.createdAt", 
    "Roles.RolesUser"."updatedAt" AS "Roles.RolesUser.updatedAt", 
    "Roles.RolesUser"."UserId" AS "Roles.RolesUser.UserId", 
    "Roles.RolesUser"."RoleId" AS "Roles.RolesUser.RoleId" 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        "Users".* 
    FROM "Users" 
    WHERE (
        SELECT 
            "UserId" 
        FROM "RolesUsers" AS "Roles.RolesUser" 
        INNER JOIN "Roles" AS "Roles" 
            ON "Roles"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."RoleId" 
        WHERE "Users"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."UserId" 
        AND "Roles"."name" IN ('member','admin') LIMIT 1
    ) IS NOT NULL LIMIT 100
) AS "Users" 
INNER JOIN "RolesUsers" AS "Roles.RolesUser" 
    ON "Users"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."UserId" 
INNER JOIN "Roles" AS "Roles" 
    ON "Roles"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."RoleId" 
    AND "Roles"."name" IN ('member','admin');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    u.*
    , r."name" AS "Roles.name"
    , r."id" AS "Roles.id"
    , ru."createdAt" AS "createdAt"
    , ru."updatedAt" AS "updatedAt"
    , ru."UserId" AS "UserId"
    , ru."RoleId" AS "RoleId"
FROM "Users" u 
JOIN "RolesUsers" ru ON u."id" = ru."UserId" 
JOIN "Roles" r ON r."id" = ru."RoleId" 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM "RolesUsers" ru2
        JOIN  "Roles" r2  ON r2."id" = ru2."RoleId"
        WHERE ru2."UserId" = u."Id"
        AND r2."name" IN ( 'member' , 'admin' )
        )
        ;
```

Comment: This is best answer for me, but it contains errors. First of all `JOIN  "Roles" r2  ON r."id" = ru2."RoleId"` should be `JOIN  "Roles" r2  ON r2."id" = ru2."RoleId"` (`r` to `r2`) and line `WHERE ru2."UserId" = u."UserId"` should be `WHERE ru2."UserId" = u."id"` (`u."UserId"` to `u."id"`) - please correct your answer and I will accept it as despite errors it is most clear to me.

Comment: [corrected] It is an obvious error; it is. Mostly caused by your mixed case identifiers, the need to quote them, and my search and-replace fixation. A lesson to be learned: dont use MixedCaseIdentifiers: they will cause errors, even trivial ones. The second one: don't call PKs `Id`; call them user_id instead, even in the `user` table . That also enables you to use the `USING` syntax.

Comment: BTW: did you notice that your original `"Roles.RolesUser"."createdAt"` (three level name) could only be valid if `roles` is the name of a schema? Just saying ...

Comment: Sorry - this is SQL generated by ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I would use analytic functions for this purpose, as in the following:

```
select ur.*
from (select u.*, ru.name as rolename, ru.id as roleid, ru.createdAt as rolecreatedat,
             sum(case when ru.name in ('member', 'admin') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by u.id) as NumMatches
      from users u join
           roleusers as ru
           on u.id = ru.userid
     ) ur
where NumMatches > 1;
```

I don't understand your table aliases scheme, where you make the table names even more complicated than they need to be.  Abbreviations usually make the query more readable.

Comment: Sorry this was generated by ORM actually. Anyway when I try to execute your query I get `ERROR: syntax error at or near "OVER"`

Comment: @user606521 . . . Yes you would get a syntax error for that; somehow I didn't finish the case statement.  Fixed now.

Comment: Hmm still you didn't declare `r` anywhere in query... `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "r"`

Answer (score 0):

You connected `Users` and `RolesUsers` by INNER JOIN, I think you need LEFT JOIN in this case.

```
SELECT "Users".*, "Roles"."name" AS "Roles.name", "Roles"."id" AS "Roles.id", "Roles.RolesUser"."createdAt" AS "Roles.RolesUser.createdAt", "Roles.RolesUser"."updatedAt" AS "Roles.RolesUser.updatedAt", "Roles.RolesUser"."UserId" AS "Roles.RolesUser.UserId", "Roles.RolesUser"."RoleId" AS "Roles.RolesUser.RoleId" 
FROM (
    SELECT "Users".* 
    FROM "Users" 
    WHERE (
        SELECT "UserId" 
        FROM "RolesUsers" AS "Roles.RolesUser" 
        INNER JOIN "Roles" AS "Roles" ON "Roles"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."RoleId" 
        WHERE "Users"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."UserId" AND "Roles"."name" IN ('member','admin') LIMIT 1
    ) IS NOT NULL LIMIT 100
) AS "Users" 
LEFT JOIN "RolesUsers" AS "Roles.RolesUser" ON "Users"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."UserId" 
INNER JOIN "Roles" AS "Roles" ON "Roles"."id" = "Roles.RolesUser"."RoleId" AND "Roles"."name" IN ('member','admin');
```

Comment: Could you point query fragment which you have added/changed (in comparison to my query)?